# Split data to 'classes' with pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, group-by

I have large csv data file with like 1000 columns that I wish to split all rows to so-called classes. The 'class' contains rows with zeros and non-zeros on the same places.

for example:
file:

```
0  ,0,0.1,0.2,0
0.9,0,0.3,0.2,0
0  ,0,0.8,0.2,0
0  ,0,0.2,0  ,0
0  ,0,0.1,0.2,0
```

will be splitted to three classes: rows 1,3,5; row2; row 4.

How this can be done in efficient way using pandas or numpy?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
In [38]: dfs = []
    ...: for _, g in df.groupby(((df == 0)*1).astype(str).sum(axis=1)):
    ...:     print(g)
    ...:     dfs.append(g)
    ...:
     0  1    2    3  4
1  0.9  0  0.3  0.2  0
     0  1    2    3  4
0  0.0  0  0.1  0.2  0
2  0.0  0  0.8  0.2  0
4  0.0  0  0.1  0.2  0
     0  1    2    3  4
3  0.0  0  0.2  0.0  0

In [39]: dfs
Out[39]:
[     0  1    2    3  4
 1  0.9  0  0.3  0.2  0,      0  1    2    3  4
 0  0.0  0  0.1  0.2  0
 2  0.0  0  0.8  0.2  0
 4  0.0  0  0.1  0.2  0,      0  1    2    3  4
 3  0.0  0  0.2  0.0  0]
```

check:

```
In [44]: [x.index.tolist() for x in dfs]
Out[44]: [[1], [0, 2, 4], [3]]
```

Explanation:

```
In [40]: df == 0
Out[40]:
       0     1      2      3     4
0   True  True  False  False  True
1  False  True  False  False  True
2   True  True  False  False  True
3   True  True  False   True  True
4   True  True  False  False  True

In [41]: ((df == 0)*1)
Out[41]:
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  1  0  0  1
1  0  1  0  0  1
2  1  1  0  0  1
3  1  1  0  1  1
4  1  1  0  0  1

In [42]: ((df == 0)*1).astype(str).sum(axis=1)
Out[42]:
0    11001.0
1     1001.0
2    11001.0
3    11011.0
4    11001.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

- find out where `df` is zero
- pretend this is a binary number and that each class is a different number.  with five columns, there should be 32 possible classes.
- use pandas `groupby` to categorize for us

---

```
g = df.groupby(df.eq(0).dot(1 << np.arange(5)))
```

show it works

```
for name, group in g:
    print(name)
    print(group)
    print('')

18
     0  1    2    3  4
1  0.9  0  0.3  0.2  0

19
     0  1    2    3  4
0  0.0  0  0.1  0.2  0
2  0.0  0  0.8  0.2  0
4  0.0  0  0.1  0.2  0

27
     0  1    2    3  4
3  0.0  0  0.2  0.0  0
```